# How do Akka and Async differ

Tags: scala, asynchronous, jvm, akka

I went to a very interesting lecture on Async (https://github.com/scala/async) a new library for Scala, what I am not sure about is how Akka and Async differ.

I am new to Scala so apologies if the answer is obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Async simplifies asynchronous and concurrent programming. Async enables programming with non-blocking APIs in a familiar direct style. Direct-style code is as simple to write as blocking code, but it has all the advantages of efficient non-blocking code.

Out-of-the-box, Async makes programming with [Scala's futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) more convenient. In fact, by using Async with futures, your easy-to-read direct-style code is transformed to highly-efficient non-blocking code under the hood. Async can also be connected to other APIs (see below).

Akka provides a programming model and runtime to simplify concurrency, distribution, and fault tolerance. Async does not provide a runtime--it makes existing abstractions and their runtimes easier to use. However, Async and Akka can work together in several important ways:

1. Using Akka's "ask" pattern, sending a message using "?" returns a future. Async makes it easy to work with those futures.
2. Async can be connected to APIs other than [Scala's Futures API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html). This opens up interesting ways to leverage Async to simplify programming with Akka actors. This is one area that we are going to explore in the near future at [Typesafe](http://www.typesafe.com/).
3. Async is a replacement for [Akka's dataflow API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/dataflow.html) which is simpler and more robust. Async is simpler, because it does not introduce complex types stemming from the use of Scala's CPS plugin. Async is more robust, since it works well together with features like pattern matching and try-catch which are not fully supported by CPS/Akka's dataflow API. Moreover, it is clearly specified where Async cannot be used (`await` cannot occur inside closures, nested classes/traits/objects, or by-name arguments).

For more Async examples and documentation see my recent [talk on Async](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/simplifying-asynchronous-code-with-scala-async-4233) and the documentation on the [Async project website](https://github.com/scala/async).

Comment: AKKA i feel it is kind or worker for long running process which require a run-time for better performance whereas async is non blocking pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Async just adds helpfull API (and some other good internal things) for working with Future and has nothing to do with Actor model while Akka is a framework for creating massively-distributed with Actors. They have different use cases and have nothing in common. It more correctly to compare Async with Scala/Akka Futures API. I don't have much experience with Async, but the main point, is that you have two constructs `async` and `await`. `Async` marks a block of asynchronous code wich contains one or more `await` calls, which marks a point at which the computation will be suspended until the awaited Future is complete. Such API can be compared with a standart way of using `map` and `flatmap` .

Using standart API (for construct translates to combination of `map` and `flatmap`):

```
def slowCalcFuture: Future[Int] = ...
val future1 = slowCalcFuture
val future2 = slowCalcFuture
def combined: Future[Int] = for {
  r1 <- future1
  r2 <- future2
} yield r1 + r2
```

And Async:

```
def slowCalcFuture: Future[Int] = ...
def combined: Future[Int] = async {
  val future1 = slowCalcFuture
  val future2 = slowCalcFuture
  await(future1) + await(future2)
}
```

Comment: Or `flow { slowCalcFuture() + slowCalcFuture() }` as a third alternative.